# Is there a way to create a new Node object from a require in one line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

We have a Node.js widget that gets exported like so:

`module.exports = ourWidget;`

I then import it into our server.js like so:

```
var ourWidget = require('./ourWidget');
var ow = new ourWidget;
```

This works as expected, **but could it be done in a single line?** EG:

```
var ow = new (require('./ourWidget'));
```

Which doesn't work, I've also tried this:

`var ow = new (require('./ourWidget')());`

Both of which resembles the code in this SO question:  [How does require work with new operator in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604497/how-does-require-work-with-new-operator-in-node-js), but both fail as soon as I try to run the code.

Comment: "*Which doesn't work*" - why? What's the problem? Do you get any errors?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40770665/1048572

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by shifting the function call to outside of the wrapping parens:

```
var ow = new (require('./ourWidget'))()
```

But keep in mind you now have no way of accessing the original widget constructor (this may or may not be a bad thing in your case).

Comment: That's [pretty much equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034941/1048572) to the `var ow = new (require('./ourWidget'))` which the OP was already using

Comment: Actually making the change to this syntax worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @Bergi No, the Op was using (require('foo')()) and your comment uses (require('foo)) when the answer above uses (require('foo'))() . The first executes the require, yours doesn't at all (just wraps the object) and the right way executes the wrapped object. New operates on the result.

Comment: @rainabba The OP wrote "*I've also tried this: `var ow = new (require('./ourWidget')());`*", but they were originally using `var ow = new (require('./ourWidget'));` (or the same with a temporary `ourWidget` variable). Which is equivalent to what this answer is suggesting.

Comment: @rainabba Not sure what you mean by "*just wraps the object*". `new` doesn't wrap anything, it constructs an instance of the operand function. The arguments parenthesis are optional.